# How to send data from javascript that related to my html and route the data to laravel 5 controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Ok, So I  already know how to connect Javascript that related to HTML and send/or get the data from PHP(in this case, without using any framework, only "plain php")

Lately, I've been using Laravel5 as my PHP framework because It seems like a great framework, I've made some simple routing to create,update,insert and delete, the action of modyfing database works like i expected.

My Laravel 5 code for routes, the controller and for create.blade.php looks like code below

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', [
    'as' => '/', 
    'uses' => 'PagesController@getIndex'
]);

Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');
```

**ProductController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use DB;

use App\Product;

use resources\views\products;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       $product = DB::select('select * from feedback');
       echo "<script>console.log('tes')</script>";
        return view('products.index')
          ->with('product',$product);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
         echo "<script>console.log('tes')</script>";
        return view('products.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
         echo "<script>console.log('tes')</script>";
       /*$rating = new Product;
       $rating->Name= $request->name;
       $rating->avg=$request->price;
       $rating->save();*/

       $inputs= $request->all();
       $product= Product::create($inputs);

      //return redirect()->route('product.index');
       return redirect()->action('ProductController@index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
         echo "<script>console.log('tes')</script>";
        //'$product= Product::where('idoveralRating',$id)->first();
        $product = Product::find($id);
        echo "<script>console.log('yes')</script>";
        //return $product;
        return view('products.show')
            ->with('product',$product);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *

     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
        // $product= Product::all();

        $product= Product::where('idoveralRating', $id)->first();

        return view('products.edit')
            ->with('product',$product);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $product->Name = $request->Name;
        $product->Avg = $request->Avg;
        $product->save();

        $product = Product::find($id);

        return redirect()->route('product.index');

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {

         $product= Product::find($id) ->delete();

        return redirect()->route('product.index');

    }
}
```

**create.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('Head')
    <title>Create new product</title>
@stop

@section('Body')
@include('pages.addVisit')

{!!Form::open(['route'=>'product.store'])!!}
{!!Form::label('name','name')!!}
{!!Form::text('Name',null,['placeholder'=>'give a name'])!!}

{!!Form::label('price','Price')!!}
{!!Form::text('price','$0',['placeholder'=>'give a price'])!!}

{!!Form::submit('create')!!}

{!!Form::close()!!}
@stop
```

Right now, I'm trying to create new data by sending my data from javascript to ProductController.php and run the method to create then save the data which is the public function store(Request $request),which i need to send the data to the product/create

So here is my function of ajax in myJs looks like

**myJs.js**

```
 function addNameThroughtLaravelController(){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST", "laravel/public/product/create", false);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        req.send("Name=Jeremy");
    }
```

The problem that I'm facing now is that I'm trying to send my data to store method at ProductController, but it seems like the post method not allowed in this case(console return the error of method not allowed, which is relate to my post method from javascript)

I don't know yet, but is it possible to send data from javascript that related to html to laravel .blade.php and or controller? (which is i believe it should be)

**Some important summary for what i expected**

Input : Click the html and the javascript send data to ProductController@Store

Output : I update the database based on Name i send from javascript from my laravel controller

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `Route::resource()` method, as I usually just have a `Route::get()` and `Route::post()` for basic CRUD operations.

`Method not allowed` means that the current request method (in your case `POST`) is not valid for the route you're trying to `POST` to. So, if you modify your `Routes.php` file to include something similar to the following:

```
Route::post("laravel/public/product/create", "ProductController@store");
```

You should be able to view the data being sent to the `public function store()` in `ProductController.php`.

Check here for the full documentation on [Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm still unable to figure it out how to  send my data from javascript and route my data....i tried like you said and it still didnt work, is it possible to pass data directly to RESTful Resource Controllers(in this case is http://localhost/Kevin/laravel/public/product/create) or should i pass it to .php(example routes.php)?

Comment: somehow i think that it is impossible to pass my data directly to ProductController, because there are more than 1 method inside my class that accept http request(so pass data to localhost/Kevin/laravel/public/product directly is impossible, i should pass the data to create method which is http://localhost/Kevin/laravel/public/product/create but somehow the create method didnt accept request!,he send the value from view called create to my store method inside ProductController, how to solve this?